# extract variable from imported HTML/JS file

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, filereader

I have HTML file that has `<script>` tag and in that scrip among other code there is a variable that holds array of data.
I need to extract that var/data.
Only solution I can think of is to find patterns in imported file (with filereader, before JSON.parse), and split it in crucial points, eg. on array start

```
var data = [
```

and at the end `}];`
but I'm afraid that's not 100% sure.
Is there any clean method in those situation that I can target inner variable and extract it?
HTML file is uniquely structured, but array data is different for every file.

Comment: so you want to pull in an external javascript file and read data that it contains ?

Comment: Are you loading this file via XHR, or are you operating on this file open in a tab?

Comment: I'm loading file from chrome extension options page (tab, locally)

Comment: I will share js fiddle with what I'm understand so far

Comment: @AbrahamAdam yes, but there is a lot of unnecessary data there, I just need that array to save it to localstorage

Comment: I'm still not sure, are you loading the HTML file as an external file via AJAX/XHR?

Comment: @Xan no, I'm loading local file with fileReader. On button click, prompt is opened, choose file,--> then function starts {var files = e.target.files, rN = new FileReader(); rN.onload = saveData;rN.readAsText(files[0]);} ... in saveData I'm parsing result of reader and saving it to localstorage

Comment: The only question I have left is _why_.

Comment: o c'mon :).. those are old Opera browser data that needs to be loaded

Comment: how else should I import it if JSON object is exported inside HTML file?

Answer (score 1):

Here is your load your script from external pages, or from external resources, more details if you do not understand.

moment.js load via jquery,
script loaded via javscript eval

Copy paste this only in Chrome console and understand what's happening:

```
//In my example using plain html let say ajax result or jquery load
//Note that if <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script> here different approach is required 


$.getScript( "http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.9.0/moment.min.js" )
  .done(function( script, textStatus ) {
    parseScript(true);
  });
function parseScript(go)
{  
    if (go)
    {
        var xhr = $('<div><script>alert("Evaluated becouse values are not set");</script><script>var1=0;</script><div class="xx"></div><script>cars =["Saab", "Volvo", "BMW"];</script><div><script>alert("Not executed because values are set")</script></div></div>');
        //var1 in global scope
        var1 = undefined;
        //cars in global scope;
        cars = undefined;
        $(xhr).filter("script").each( function(e) { 
            if (var1 != undefined && cars != undefined ) return;
            console.log(moment().format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a') + '  ______ script executed ' + $(this).html());
            eval($(this).html());
            alert(moment().format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a') + ' _______ var1: ' + var1 + ' cars: ' + cars);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I appreciate your effort, but i think this is a little bit overkill for my need. I ended using splice before parsing string.